# Rails form for models who are related

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a patient app in rails for college. I need to create a form for a patient report.

The patients, and reports have a relationship

My models

User, Patient and Report models:

```
    class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

      include Tire::Model::Search
      include Tire::Model::Callbacks

      validates :name, presence:true
      validates :age, presence:true
      validates :phone, presence:true
      validates :ailment, presence:true
      validates :apointment, presence:true
      validates :status, presence:true

      belongs_to :user
      has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy

      def to_s
        name
      end
    end

    class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :patient
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Clearance::User

      has_many :patients
      has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

Routes:

```
           reports GET    /reports(.:format)                      reports#index
                   POST   /reports(.:format)                      reports#create
        new_report GET    /reports/new(.:format)                  reports#new
       edit_report GET    /reports/:id/edit(.:format)             reports#edit
            report GET    /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#show
                   PATCH  /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#update
                   PUT    /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#update
                   DELETE /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#destroy
```

This is the report controller

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_patient
    before_action :find_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :require_login
    def new
        @reports = Report.new 
    end 

    def show 
    end

    def create
        @report = Report.new(report_params)
        @report.user_id = current_user_id
        @report.patient_id = @patient.id

        if @report.save
            redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @report.update(report_params)
            redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
        else 
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @report.destroy
        redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
    end

    private

        def report_params
            params.require(:report).permit(:date, :report)
        end

        def find_patient
            @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
        end

        def find_report
            @report = Report.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

My form

I think this is my issue. I'm not sure what I should put after the @ to allow to form post to a report for a particular user.
Any advice here.

```
<%= form_for @report  do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.text_field :date %>

<% end %>
```

Link to access form page

```
<% if signed_in? %>
        <% if @patient.id == current_user.id %>
            <%= link_to "Add Visit Report", new_report_path(patient_id: @patient.id),class: "button_one" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: You should have an idea on what the form should look like, without considering how to do it. In your question it is not clear how the user should appear, with a creation form or do you need to select it?

Comment: You need to understand the problem before you look for answer, determine what goes in your form first and then ask question if something you are trying to do is failing

Comment: @Syl It's passed in through a link. The user (doctor) is on a patients show page and clicks the link which passed the patient id through. I'll update the pos

Comment: Can't really tell wha you are trying to do but I think what you are looking for is nested resources.  See here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to, use nested resources. So your routes will look similar to this:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :reports
end
```

So routes will be as follows

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
    patient_reports GET    /patients/:patient_id/reports(.:format)          reports#index
                    POST   /patients/:patient_id/reports(.:format)          reports#create
 new_patient_report GET    /patients/:patient_id/reports/new(.:format)      reports#new
edit_patient_report GET    /patients/:patient_id/reports/:id/edit(.:format) reports#edit
     patient_report GET    /patients/:patient_id/reports/:id(.:format)      reports#show
                    PATCH  /patients/:patient_id/reports/:id(.:format)      reports#update
                    PUT    /patients/:patient_id/reports/:id(.:format)      reports#update
                    DELETE /patients/:patient_id/reports/:id(.:format)      reports#destroy
           patients GET    /patients(.:format)                              patients#index
                    POST   /patients(.:format)                              patients#create
        new_patient GET    /patients/new(.:format)                          patients#new
       edit_patient GET    /patients/:id/edit(.:format)                     patients#edit
            patient GET    /patients/:id(.:format)                          patients#show
                    PATCH  /patients/:id(.:format)                          patients#update
                    PUT    /patients/:id(.:format)                          patients#update
                    DELETE /patients/:id(.:format)                          patients#destroy
```

then modify controller actions as follows

```
def new
    @report = @patient.reports.build 
end 

def create
    @report = @patient.reports.build 
    if @report.save
        redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def find_report
    @report = @patient.reports.find(params[:id])
end
```

and view will be look like this

```
<%= form_for [@patient, @report]  do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this will solve your problem